# Can I host multiple front-ends for one back-end?

Tags: server, digital-ocean

I think my problem is common, I have to host one separate site for each one of my clients, but it's the same application, my clients could ask for specific updates (since my application have a certain flow, that can change), but the application is ready for it, we're using configuration files that are easy to update. Currently I have one server for each client, but soon I'll have a lot of trouble updating each server (imagine having to enter 50 different servers to update each one, and paying each one too).

I'm currently using Digital Ocean services for my servers.
I have an Java Spring application for back-end, one React JS for front-end, and my database it's an postgres SQL.

It is currently like this:
[image]

My idea is to use 1, 2 or 3 servers only, starting with just 1:
All my back, front and database will be inside one server, but will have onde front-end running for each site that I have, all of the front-ends will connect to one back-end, and this back-end will connect to one database (this database will have all data of all sites), since I don't want to have one database for everyone, I'm thinking about using SQL View to maneuver the data for each one of my clients. It would be like this:

[image]

Using 2 servers:
It's basically the same thing but I would use one for back-end and database and the other will contain all of my fronts, like this:

[image]

Using 3 servers:
It's basically the same thing but one server for back, one for database and one for fronts, like this:

[image]

If my client ask for a specific change (just for him) I could just create a directory for each client at my application, and change the configuration file for him, and updating for everyone would be just a git pull.

I don't have a lot of knowledge in this area, that's why I'm asking if this is doable. If it's not, how could I decrease my work updating each server? Should I look for other server service? Should I keep my servers the way they are and look for scripts?

Comment: What you are mentioning is a multi-tenant application. I am not sure what stage your solution is. If it is in late stage of development, then changing the architecture would be very difficult. You could then look at support infra / team. Managing 50 servers individually is a lot of support work.

Comment: My application and servers are already working for my clients, this should be quite a challenge to change, but hiring support to update servers wouldn't be very interesting

Comment: I've searched this multi-tenancy and found out a multi-tenancy with a database for tenant, this should be easier to achieve, since my current clients already have their database filled.

Comment: While database design is a significant part of multi-tenancy; there are other considerations too, for instance provisioning of applications etc. However, discounting that, refer: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/saas-tenancy-app-design-patterns it provides a good view into multi-tenancy considerations and patters.

Answer (score -1):

Seems easy to achieve. Just have common login page, when client logs in, authenticate and store login cookie on their device. When client requests a page just serve a page based on their authentication cookie.

```
if(client == 1){
Require(front_end_client_1.html)
exit();
}


if(client == 2){
Require(front_end_client_2.html)
exit();
}

if(client == 3){
Require(front_end_client_3.html)
exit();
}
```